# How can you get user responses from a dm? (Discord Node js bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I've started making a bot for my discord server since something happened to the last one.
I've been trying to get the bot to get the user's (it DMS) input, but can't figure out how to do this.
Down below is what I have done so far

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = 'a!';

const Commands = '!help !version !post';

const MarketplaceCommnads = "Looking for Devs For Hire Looking for Creations Sell Creations"

const Version = '1.0.0';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Help')
    .setColor('#ff0000')
    .addField('Command List', Commands)
const postEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Post")
    .setColor("#ff0000")
    .addField('The bot has dmed you')
const dmEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("New Post")
    .setColor("#ff0000")
    .addField("Create a new post", MarketplaceCommnads)
const lookingfordevsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Looking for Devs")
    .setColor("#ff0000")
    .addField("Post everything here (What you're looking for, payment, etc): ")
const versionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Version')
    .setColor('#ff0000')
    .addField('Version', Version)
    .setColor('#ff0000')


client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot ) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'help'){
        message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
    }
    if (command === 'version'){
        message.channel.send(versionEmbed);
    }
    if (command === 'post'){
        message.channel.send(postEmbed);
        message.author.send(dmEmbed);
        const Message = Response()
        if (Message === 'Looking for Devs'){
            message.author.send(lookingfordevsEmbed);
        }
    }
});
```

I've used Node JS before, but this is the first time I've created a bot, so I'm trying to learn how all of this works so this may seem like an obvious error. Solutions I have tried before making this question: Youtube and Googling

Comment: `Channel#awaitMessages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can first check if it is a DM by using Message#channel and seeing if it is a DMChannel and to get their User you can do Message#author which returns a User.
Here is the documentation for each things I have talked about

> Message: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message
>
> DMChannel: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel
>
> User: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User

Hope this helped!